# Change default cookie names in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to change the default Cookie name for .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxx in ASP.NET Core 3.X MVC, however I do not seem to find any documentation on it. Is it even possible?

The only one I found to be able to alter was this:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
  options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
  options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
  options.ConsentCookie.Name = "GDRP";
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is achievable using [`AddAntiforgery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.antiforgeryservicecollectionextensions.addantiforgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Here's an example taken from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#antiforgery-options) and modified accordingly:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => 
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourCookieName";
});
```

There's a useful page in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#api-usage-with-samesite) that lists the built-in ASP.NET Core cookies and where the configuration for each comes from.

Answer (score 6):

**For .NET 5.0 and higher**

in `ProjectRoot/Startup.cs` class

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "your_cookie_name";
        });
    // ...
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Comment: This didnt work for me in .NET 8, [but this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/219189/how-to-modify-aspnetcore-identity-application-cook) answer on Microsoft QA solved it for me (the one in the comments). E.g. `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.Cookie.Name = "your_cookie_name");`

Answer (score 3):

ok, found it already, for those that are looking

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
     options.Cookie.Name = "my-x-name";
     options.HeaderName = "my-x-name";
});
```

It will accept any string, need to validate if it works or if something else needs to be updated...